# Questions re regex in python

Tags: python, regex

In this regex code:

```
   ((?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\*[+\s]\d{1,2}[,]{0,1}[+\s]\d{4})
```

What do the following code mean?:

```
[+\s]
```

and:

```
 \*
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/0Q2W7C/1

Comment: answer `[+\s]` means one of plus or whitespace. taker more ink to put dupr link on er

Comment: @Edward cheers!